# How to avoid doing a move with Box?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a method which I want to give a Box which holds a struct that implements the `std::io::Write` trait. This is because in my program I want it to write to stdout, but in my tests I want it to write to a buffer and produce a string from that buffer to validate my program.

I am doing something like this in my program:

```
let stdOutWriter = Box::new(io::stdout());
write_output(&mut results, stdOutWriter);
```

where write_output calls:

```
let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(writer);
```

In my tests, I want to call:

```
let writer = Box::new(io::BufWriter::new(Vec::new()));
write_output(&mut results, writer).unwrap();
let bytes = Box::new(writer.into_inner().unwrap());
// I plan to validate this string later
let string = String::from_utf8(*bytes).unwrap();
```

The issue is that write_output consumes the writer, so I can't call writer.into_inner(). So I try to change it into a reference:

```
let mut writer = Box::new(io::BufWriter::new(Vec::new()));
write_output(&mut results, &mut writer).unwrap();
```

and now I get:

> mismatched types expected mutable reference `&mut Box<(dyn std::io::Write + 'static)>`
> found mutable reference `&mut Box<BufWriter<Vec<u8>>>`

How do I get around these issues?

edit:

The signature of write_output is:

```
fn write_output(results: &HashMap<u16, ResultRecord>,writer: &mut Box<dyn io::Write>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
```

Comment: What is the signature of `write_output`?

Comment: Your code works for me when the signature is: `fn write_output(_results: &mut Vec<u8>, _writer: impl io::Write) -> Option<String>`.

Comment: I added the signature of write_output.

Comment: And the signature of that function is outside of your control? It seems quite unnecessarily constrained.

Comment: I see, I should have used impl io::Write... I thought I would need to use a Box. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function signature is unnecessarily constrained. In particular, `&mut Box<dyn io::Write>` also implements `io::Write`, so you could just as easily declare the type of the `writer` parameter to be `impl io::Write`. That would allow anything that satisfies `&mut Box<dyn io::Write>` and plenty more.

```
fn write_output(results: &HashMap<u16, ResultRecord>, writer: impl io::Write) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;
```

When you call it, you could pass a boxed writer:

```
let writer = Box::new(io::BufWriter::new(Vec::new()));
write_output(&mut results, writer);
```

Or a mutable reference to a boxed writer:

```
let mut writer = Box::new(io::BufWriter::new(Vec::new()));
write_output(&mut results, &mut writer);
```

Or any other writer:

```
let stderr = io::stderr();
let writer = stderr.lock();
write_output(&mut results, writer).unwrap();
```